# Assigning labels to different group assignment scenarios

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a `data.frame` that assigns `id`s to `group`s. In the simplest scenario each `id` is assigned to a different `group`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = c("a1","a2"),
                  id = c("i1","i2"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

In a second scenario all `id`s are assigned to one `group`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(group = c("a1","a1"),
                  id = c("i1","i2"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And in the third scenario there's ambiguous `id` to `group` assignment:

```
df3 <- data.frame(group = c("a1","a2","a2"),
                  id = c("i1","i1","i2"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I'm looking for a function that would return a label `"scenario1"/"scenario2"/"scenario3"` given such a `data.frame` with the `id` and `group` columns, according to the scenarios above.

In other words, this function would return `"scenario1"` for `df1`, `"scenario2"` for `df2`, and `"scenario3"` for `df3`

Obviously this can be done with `if` statements but I'm hoping for something faster using `dplyr`/`tidyverse` or `data.table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function to check different conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

return_scenario <- function(df) {
  tmp <- df %>% distinct(group, id)
  case_when(
    n_distinct(tmp$group) == 1 ~ 'scenario 2',
    n_distinct(tmp$id) == nrow(tmp) ~ 'scenario 1', 
    TRUE ~ 'scenario 3') 
}

return_scenario(df1)  
#[1] "scenario 1"  
return_scenario(df2) 
#[1] "scenario 2"   
return_scenario(df3)  
#[1] "scenario 3"
```

If needed, this can also be translated in base R/`data.table` with their equivalent functions.